# How to avoid calling a base method twice when the child class calls it and so does one of the parent classes that is also called

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have the following code about a wildlife park:

```
public class Bird
{
  public void virtual Exercise()
  {
     some logic here
  }

  public void virtual Feed()
  {
     Exercise();

     some logic here
  }
}


public class Penguin : Bird
{
  public void override Exercise()
  {
     base.Exercise();
     some logic here
  }

  public void override Feed()
  {
     Exercise();
     base.Feed();
     some logic here
  }
}
```

So everytime a bird is feed it must also be exercised. However a bird can be exercised without being fed.

A penguin is a special type of bird which requires bird exercise and some specific penguin exercise. Feeding the penguin requires bird feeding plus some additional penguin requirements.

The problem I have here with this code is when Feed is called it gets the bird exercise twice. The penguins will get really tired.

How could I improve the code so that when the penguins are fed they are only exercised for bird and penguin once per feed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just remove Exercise() from the Penguin.Feed() call.  Since, as you note, Exercise() will get called when you call base.Feed(), so it's redundant to do so.  And the base.Feed() call will call the Penguin version of Exercise(), so you'll get the right exercise for that bird.

(Removed reference to mammal since it was removed from the question)